# converting character list to list of strings with each one contains 3 characters in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to convert list of character to list of strings with each one contains 3 characters using Prolog.

For example, ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] will be converted to ["abc", "def"].

What I tried was

```
toTriplets([H1|[H2|[H3|T]]],[F|R]) :- string_concat(H1,H2,X) , string_concat(X,H3,F) , toTriplets(T,R).
```

However, this gives me false when I execute the command

```
?- toTriplets(['a','b','c','d','e','f'],X).
false.
```

What is the problem with my code? I really can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're missing the *base case* of recursion.
For instance

```erlang
toTriplets([],[]).
```

Indeed there you have *the* chance to decide if accept only triples - as above -  or accept also incomplete ones, like

```erlang
toTriplets([A,B],[AB]) :- string_concat(A,B,AB).
toTriplets([A],[S]) :- atom_string(A,S).
```